# Java: extending Thread without implementing run()

Tags: java, multithreading

I am a technical writer who knows some Java and I have been tasked with tracing the threads in some old, highly threaded Java code.  The code's original author is not here anymore so we are trying to figure out exactly how it works.  I have come across a class that extends `Thread` but does not implement a `run()` method.  What would be the point of extending `Thread` but not implementing `run()` (if any)?

I did notice that one of the methods of this class is `synchronized`:

```
public synchronized void incrementCounter() {
  this.counter++;
}
```

but all of the other methods seem to be non-synchronized.  In fact, most of the other methods are just getters and setters.  Is extending `Thread` or implementing `Runnable` necessary in order to declare a method `synchronized`?  Thanks!

Comment: Is the class abstract? Maybe it serves as a base class for other classes and implement a common logic that could be shared across various subclasses.

Comment: J-D beat me to it...  This could make sense if it were a base class for further subclasses that do implement run().

Comment: The class is not abstract.  The signature is `public class XXX extends Thread` and it gets instantiated from inside a different class.

Comment: Sounds like someone wanted to associate a counter with each thread for some reason.  Reasonably legit if they were trying to gather statistics on certain attributes of the threading.  (Of course, some code somewhere needs to increment the counter, but presumably that's in other classes.)

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the code that uses it?

Answer (score 3):

My *guess* is that this older code was written before some of the standard thread pool libraries, ExecutorService, etc.  So maybe it was the company's attempt to implement similar functionality.  (or else a not invented here response)  So long as the code always does

```
Thread thread = new ThisSpecialThreadClass(someRunnable);
thread.start();
```

you will get whatever "benefits" it has, and, as you note in your comment, it should eventually call `someRunnable.run().`

Comment: +1 this assumes that there is a constructor on the thread class which calls super(Runnable).

Comment: The weird thing is that this class is not instantiated like the above example and start() is never called on it.  It is simply instantiated like `specialClass = new SpecialThreadClass(arg1, arg2);`.  I am thinking the `extends Thread` is some kind of copy/paste mistake.

Comment: So there are a number of constructors.  There is a `(Runnable, String)` one.  I bet `arg1` is `Runnable` and the constructor is `super(arg1, arg2);` so that is setting your runnable @user1002119.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no use of `super()` in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the point of extending Thread but not implementing run()

As @Mik378 mentions, there is little to no point in doing this.  Without overriding the `run()` method, the thread is going to start and finish immediately.

> Is extending Thread or implementing Runnable necessary in order to declare a method synchronized?

No, they have nothing to do with each other.  You don't need to create any threads to make use of `synchronized` methods.  The object that is `synchronized` is the instance of the method and whichever thread is calling it (even if it is the "main" thread) will synchronize on that object.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at a class extending `Thread` (although being not recommended) and not implementing the `run` method, sounds like being an `abstract` class. Check for that.

Besides, the answer to your second question is definitely **No**:

`synchronised` never expects the wrapping class to extend `Thread` or implement `Runnable` since a thread is not associated to a specific class but spans one or several ones.

If you assert that the concerned class is not `abstract`, I suspect the `Thread` type you see, is indeed a custom type belonging to another package(different than `java.lang.Thread`) ... and has nothing to do with a Thread class: ugly but possible...